# VB.net and MYSQL5 connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm having a great deal of trouble finding code examples to connect a VB.net client application I am writing to a MYSQL5 database.  I am trying to access a database I created through WAMP and phpMyAdmin.

where on the internet is a simple example of a programmatic implementation of an object I can use to connect these two seemingly un-connectable entities?

Just to make it a bit clearer:

I have a DB made through phpMyAdmin called: test
within the db is a table: sys_users
within the table are: user_ID (pk), user_name, user_password

simply looking to connect VB.net to test and query the table sys_users, returning a boolean if they exist.  From there, I can figure out the rest of my solution for my program dealing with other tables and data.

thanks for any help in this.

Comment: You mean password_**hash**, right? Don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: no. just code to connect.  Right now I'm not worried about security with the app.  Its going to be stored and run on a local machine with no internet access and the users are only logging in to parse the data they have saved regarding tables which they have been granted access too.  The data in this DB is trivial, its only set in the environment to facilitate easy lookup and reference.

Comment: Still, some of your users will re-use passwords they use on public sites, some of them likely sensitive. The axiom remains: **DON'T STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT!**

Comment: fair enough, but that is secondary,  I need to be able to access the information first.

Comment: Look in the "Related" section to the bottom, right of this page.  It provides links to basically existing duplicates of this question.  Did you search for existing questions with answers before posting your question, as the site instructs?

Comment: I haven't looked at those other Qs but, in short, install Connector/Net and then connect to your database exactly as you would any other using ADO.NET.  You can get connection strings from www.connectionstrings.com.

Comment: yes, i have and even tried some of the solutions; however, most if not all of the code I've seen is unusable for one reason or another.  When using it, I get some form of database connection error.

Answer (score 0):

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class login
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim strConStr As String = "Data Source=localhost;uid=********;pwd=********;database=********"
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection
        conn = New MySqlConnection(strConStr)
        MsgBox(conn.ConnectionString.ToString)

```
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Opened Successfully")
        conn.Close()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to Database: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Yes, this was a problem for someone else, but the solution seems to work so far.   As for the Password validation etc, I will most definitely make use of it.  All I needed guys, thanks.